# php file upload validation and error displaying

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have a form with one of the inputs as a file upload. i have a php script that i call with jquery ajax to validate the other form fields and display error messages in a div above the form. it does this using .html() jquery function, based on a php echo that is very similar to the following script.

i have also created a php script to validate a file upload, looks like this:

```
<?php

    $errorList = array();
    $inc = 0;


    $allowedExt = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
    $fileExt = end(explode(".", $_FILES['imgUpload']['name']));
    if((($_FILES['imgUpload']['type'] == 'image/gif')
     || ($_FILES['imgUpload']['type'] == 'image/pnjpeg')
     || ($_FILES['imgUpload']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'))
     && ($_FILES['imgUpload']['size'] < 2000000)
     && in_array($fileExt, $allowedExt)){
    if($_FILES['imgUpload']['error'] > 0)){

        $errorList[$inc++] = '<span class="error"> File error:'. $_FILES['imgUpload']['error'].'</span>';
    }

    }
    else{
    $errorList[$inc++] = '<span class="error"> Invalid file </span>';

    }

    echo '<ul class="errorList">';
    for($i =0; $i<$inc; $i++){
        echo $errorList[$i];

    }
    echo '</ul>';


?>
```

i want the error messages that are in this script to be displayed in a similar fashion to the others, but as ive read, file uploading cant be done using ajax.

anyone got any suggestions for how i can go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File upload is not possible by Ajax. But you can use IFrame to make it look like Ajax.

Your options are:

- The hidden iframe trick, popularized by Google. Implementing this yourself can result in some klunky stuff so there are libraries out there, such as jQuery, which have plugins, such as jQuery's popular Form Plugin, that automate this so you don't have to feel dirty inside when using it.
- Using Flash to faciliate the process. Most notably SWFUpload is very popular. All things being equal, I'd probably go with the Javascript solution over this, but I've used this in the past with success. The cool thing about this solution is that it comes with a nicer interface such as loading indicators and thumbnails and such. At this point, though, you're asking for a user to have Flash + Javascript available, which may not work in some situations.
- Using Silverlight instead of Flash, although I wouldn't really consider this as a viable solution, as it has a much lower penetration rate than the other two solutions.

FOr your help, see this example

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_ajax_example__asynchronous_file_upload.xml

It is using Iframe option

Comment: <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0px;height:0px;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmXMLUpload"  target="upload_target" action="scripts/uploadXML.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return checkExtension(fXMLFile.value, 'xml')">
<!--only allow up to 30k of data to be uploaded-->
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
<input name="fXMLFile" id="fXMLFile" type="file" accept="text/xml" size="50" />
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>

Comment: Souce : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725888/uploading-a-file-via-ajax-with-php

Comment: nice suggestion dude. this might sound a bit noobish, but files are uploaded after the form is submitted right?

Comment: Yes, form will be submitted, but it will keep the page because of iframe. try that :)